# How to vieuw my website in ubuntu server

Tags: server

I tried to set up a webserver in Ubuntu server. Then i want to add my website/database to it.

The problem is that i can't see my own website. First i saw the default Ubuntu page, i removed this in /var/www/html en placed my .html page with the .css page and a folder with photo's. 
I read something that i have to change the file etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf . But i don't now what.

When i go to the website is just see the index of the directory /var/www/html
which is 
- photo/ (folder)
- fotoboek.css
- fotoboek.html

How can i see my website?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, by default apache will only look for index.html in any given folder. That can be changed via the `DirectoryIndex` directive in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. However, to be consistent with how most people do it, you should rename `fotoboek.html` to `index.html`. If you insist, then add this to your Directory stanza in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf':

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                DirectoryIndex index.html fotoboek.html
        </Directory>
```

Comment: Ok thanks this worked ! Now i have still one problem, i see my website but i don't see the photo's. The photo's are located in a separate folder. Do i need to link this folder or something?

Comment: Well, I assume the links in fotoboek.html include the folder name "./photo/picture01.jpg" or whatever. Otherwise I don't know without more information.

Comment: I found it, i changed the folder name in linux, so the link wasn't correct in fotoboek.html. Thanks for your help